# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite setSize not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I'm currently developing a custom plugin and I don't quite understand why a Composite element takes all the space even if other Composite elements are present.

My Handler for the execution of the plugin goes like this:

```
public class IwokGeneratorHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        Shell shell = window.getShell();
        ApplicationWindow win = new ApplicationWindow(shell) {

            @Override
            protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {

                parent.setSize(800, 600);
                //first panel
                Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
                //x, y, width, height
                composite.setBounds(10, 10, 424, 70);

                //second panel
                Composite composite_1 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
                composite_1.setBounds(10, 86, 424, 309);

                //third panel
                Composite composite_2 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
                composite_2.setBounds(10, 407, 424, 42);

                return parent;
            }
        };
        win.open();
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, the first Composite takes all the space of the main Application window and the others cannot be seen, whatever the window size it is. I checked it multiple times.

Is there any property I'm missing to prevent elements to autifill?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you intentionally not set any layouts or layout data? https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationWindow` expects the `createContents` method to return a single `Composite` containing all the controls in the content (as do most other JFace window and dialog classes).

So something like:

```java
  protected Control createContents(final Composite parent) {

      parent.setSize(800, 600);

      // Main body composite
      Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

      //first panel
      Composite composite = new Composite(body, SWT.NONE);
      //x, y, width, height
      composite.setBounds(10, 10, 424, 70);

      //second panel
      Composite composite_1 = new Composite(body, SWT.NONE);
      composite_1.setBounds(10, 86, 424, 309);

      //third panel
      Composite composite_2 = new Composite(body, SWT.NONE);
      composite_2.setBounds(10, 407, 424, 42);

      // Return the body
      return body;
  }
```

Note that your code is also returning `parent` which is wrong - it must be the created composite.

Note: Although using `setBounds` may look simple to start with it will cause problems if the code runs on different machines with different font sizes (or control sizes if you run on macOS/Linux/Windows). Using Layouts is strongly recommended.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it now. Properly using the main Composite as you said did the trick. I'll take the advice on the layouts too.